# Limiting Distribution of Sample Mean.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image: Maths Questions]

I do not know how to do d) and e) but I think it has something to do with Central Limit Theorem and using Taylor Expansion. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have done some working and I think d) may correspond to a Normal distribution with $\text{mean} = 1$ and $\text{variance} = 0$, but am very unsure.

For (a) I got a Negative Binomial MGF $\mathrm{NegBin}(3 , 0.75)$ which came to 
$$M_{Y_3}(t)= \frac{(0.75e^t)^3}{(1-0.25e^t)^3}$$

for (b) I got $\mathrm{NegBin}(n , 0.75)$
$$M_{Y_n}(t)=\frac{(0.75e^t)^n}{(1-0.25e^t)^n}$$

for (c) I got an MGF of 
$$M_{\text{sample mean}}(t)=\frac{(0.75e^{t/n})^n}{(1-0.25e^{t/n})^n}$$

Comment: You should include the answers you found to the previous parts because it would be easier for someone reading this question and willing to answer to not have to work on the previous parts. For example part c seems critical for part d, so plz include the answers you found to previous parts.

Comment: Ok sure thing for